# Neural compute stick (ncsdk) - dispatcherEventReceive() Read Failed -1 error

Tags: ncsdk

I am trying to test the working condition of NCS (Neural Computing Stick) Device
by running a *hello_ncs_py*: Movidius Neural Compute Stick Hello World example for Python
.

The program runs fine recognizes the input device, open() and close() functions of the NCS device are working fine. NCS device is opened and closed successfully.

But at the end of the program it gives a dispatchEventReceive() Read Failed -1 error.

Entire output of is mentioned below.

```
$~/Documents/workspace/ncsdk-2.05.00.02/examples/apps/hello_ncs_py$ make run

making run
python3 hello_ncs.py;
D: [         0] ncDeviceCreate:307  ncDeviceCreate index 0

D: [         0] ncDeviceCreate:307  ncDeviceCreate index 1

D: [         0] ncDeviceOpen:501    File path /usr/local/lib/mvnc/MvNCAPI-ma2450.mvcmd

I: [         0] ncDeviceOpen:507    ncDeviceOpen() XLinkBootRemote returned success 0

I: [         0] ncDeviceOpen:536    XLinkConnect done - link Id 0

D: [         0] ncDeviceOpen:550    done

I: [         0] ncDeviceOpen:552    Booted 3-ma2450 -> VSC

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:373    Device attributes

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:376    Device FW version: 2.4.2450.f0

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:378    mvTensorVersion 2.4 

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:379    Maximum graphs: 10

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:380    Maximum fifos: 20

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:382    Maximum graph option class: 1

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:384    Maximum device option class: 1

I: [         0] getDevAttributes:385    Device memory capacity: 522073264

Hello NCS! Device opened normally.
I: [         0] ncDeviceClose:742   closing device

E: [         0] dispatcherEventReceive:200  dispatcherEventReceive() Read failed -1

Goodbye NCS! Device closed normally.
NCS device working.
```

The below output line is the error. I am not sure, whether this is a big issue.

```
E: [         0] dispatcherEventReceive:200  dispatcherEventReceive() Read failed -1
```

The following discussion forum https://ncsforum.movidius.com/discussion/840/how-do-i-test-if-the-ncs-is-in-working-condition gives information that this is caused by VM bugs.

So, they ask us to setup VM USB filters. And then proceed.

I have also setup VM USB filters as mentioned in the link https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/vm_config.html. The error is still persisting.

System Configuration: 
Ubuntu 16.04 - virtual machine, 
RAM allocated - 4gb

My question is, is this a trivial error and is there any accurate solution to rectify this issue?